# NetLogo: Summing up the first element of a list in a list

Tags: list, netlogo

I have a list that contains elements that are lists with two entries themselves:

list1 [ [15, w1] [20, w2] [30, w3] ...]

now, in a different function, I want to include a sum of the first element in each of the lists in list1 (i.e. 15 + 20 +30 ...)

what I've tried is

```
let weigh_dem (t_d_f * price_w) - (sum (foreach list1 [[a b] -> a] ))
```

but I get the error message "expected reporter.

Since I'm new on netlogo I would be glad to get advice on this, also if there is a previous post about this that I didn't see, I'd be happy to get a hint! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [`map`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map) instead of `foreach`. It works pretty much just like `foreach` except that it returns the results in a list (whereas `foreach` just executes the command for each item in the list). Also, the argument to the anonymous procedure when using either `foreach` or `map` on `list1` will be a list containing the two items. So you need to use `first` to get the first item out:

```
let weigh_dem t_d_f * price_w - sum map [ pair -> first pair ] list1
```

Comment: No problem! Make sure to mark the answer correct so that other's know this question has been answered.